# Remove all words (either digit or non-digit) after the list of specific words in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the variable named address (without state, city and zipcode) below:

| **address** |
| --- |
| 123 HAPPY RD |
| 456 CHEERS ST |
| 789 BEAUTIFUL DR E |
| 218 WILDWOOD LN C1 |

I want to remove all redundant words after a list of street types (RD, DR, LN, ST) in SAS.

Desired output:

| **address** |
| --- |
| 123 HAPPY RD |
| 456 CHEERS ST |
| 789 BEAUTIFUL DR |
| 218 WILDWOOD LN |

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: I just figure out and would like to post here for any one who have the same issue:

**desired=prxchange('s/(.*)([ ,]+RD|AVE|DR|CV|PLZ)(.*)/$1$2/', -1, address);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data want;
    set have;

    * Parse a regular expression to find RD, AVE, ... ;
    *     as one word (\b indicates word boundery) ;
    * For efficiency parce the regular expression only for the first observation;
    if _N_ eq then _rxStreet = prxParse("\b(RD|AVE|DR|CV|PLZ)\b)";
    retain _rxStreet ;
    
    * look for the regular expression;
    if prxMatch(_rxStreet, address) then do;
        * determine the position and length of the last occurence ;
        call prxPasn(_rxStreet, -1, address, _pos, _len);
        address = substr(address, 1, _pos + _len -1);
    end;
    drop _:; forget all variables that start with underscore ;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk for your wisdom. Do you know how we can extract the address street name only? Desired outcome would be 
123 happy 
456 Cheers
789 beautiful 

(remove all street types, some street name also contains two words instead of one word, ie: 123 sound beautiful St --> want: 123 sound beautiful)

Comment: See `prxposn` in https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/perl_regexp/regexp-tip-sheet.pdf, but with real life data, you are definitely running into troubles, for instance with addresses like `12a SOME ST` or `456 MARKET`